# Angular Material Table Filter that shows only the first filtered row - the first match - strict filter

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, material-table

I have a material table filter, 
 but how to create a strict filter, that shows only the first match.....the first filtered row???

The standard function with multiple filter:

```
  if (typeof(filterValue) === 'undefined'){
    filterValue = '';
  }
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function( source, filter: string): boolean {
  return source.stopIndex.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter);
  };
  filterValue = filterValue.toString();
  filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // remove whitespace
  filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
```